# merging to find only unique values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, pymongo, primary-key

I have a simple requirement to insert data into the mongo db only if the data is not present based on a primary key(My primary key is a combination of 3 attributes item_id, process_name and actor) using lambda script. Explanation on what I am doing currently:

1). df is the dataframe loaded from the input csv file, it will have only those headers for the process. This df data has to be inserted into my db.

```
df = wr.s3.read_csv(path=part_file_url, low_memory=False)
df = df[header]
```

NOTE: header will have the primary key attributes along with additional default attributes for insertion.

2). I query my collection basis process name and id. Further, i use project_keys to bring in only the primary key of all records from db as follows:

```
project_keys ={'_id': 0, 'item_id': 1, 'process_name': 1, 'actor': 1}

"queryString": [ "item_id", "process_name","actor"]

curr_data_df = pd.DataFrame(list(audit_collection.find({"process_name":process_name, "processId":process_id}, project_keys)), columns=queryString)
```

3). Now to find the unique values, I do the following:

```
result = df.merge(curr_data_df,how='left', indicator=True) #step 3.a
result = result[result['_merge']=='left_only'] # step 3.b
df = result.drop(columns='_merge') # step 3.c
```

Once i fetch the unique values in df, I change every item in df and do insert_many into my collection.

Queries:

1. Is my above solution of finding unique values in input df with left merging basis primary key right?
2. In my merge function, I dont specify any column names as from my database i bring in only the primary key columns and my df will already have those 3 keys. So by default will it take the common merge columns as "item_id", "process_name","actor" or i have to specifically specify it again. During my testing with small data in python shell, above had worked. But wanted this confirmed,
3. I saw one weird case today and unable to figure out:
   I uploaded a same file second time to check if this data duplication check works. See the logs:

```
Number of records in original input df: 148  (df from step 1)
Original MONGODB source data-> Number of records: 684, Number of columns: 3 (curr_data_df from step 2)
Merge input*mongodb -> Number of records: 4166, Number of columns: 53 (step 3.a)
Unique new records -> Number of records after removing duplicates: 0, Number of columns: 53 (step 3.b)
Input df Unique records -> Number of records in final df: 0, Number of columns: 53 (step 3.c)
```

So though the df correwctly identified that unique new records is 0 in last step but why in step 3.a merge records was 4166 wherein the input had only 148 records and database data has only 684 records. Any insights here?